# How to determine if slow-deployed application is deployed correctly?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I have a Jenkins project that builds an application and then, if successful, copies the application to our test-environment and restarts the Tomcat server. The Tomcat startup takes around 90 seconds. How can I automatically and / or programmatically check if the Tomcat startup was successful so I can trigger a deploy to our staging environment? We have a monitor URL I could monitor, but I have no clues on how to implement this in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply solved this by setting up a simple exec-job in Jenkins that executes the following command.

```
curl -f -m 120 -o /dev/null -s -S http://example.org:8080/application
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an ant scriptlet, and put two things into a [parallel](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) task:

- Starting Tomcat with [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task
- a [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) element with socket listener for the http port of tomcat inside a [waitfor](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html). You can define the timout property, and if it is defined after the waitfor, you can use [fail](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) to fail the build. To check the property you can simply create a subtarget with conditional running and after waitfor you can call it.

So something like this:

```
<target name="runCheckedTomcat">
    <parallel>
        <sequential>
            <echo>Tomcat starts</echo>
            <exec command="start.bat" dir="tomcatdir">
            </exec>
        </sequential>
        <sequential>
            <waitfor timeoutproperty="timeout" maxwait="15" maxwaitunit="second">
                <socket server="localhost" port="8080"/>
            </waitfor>
            <antcall target="fail"/>
        </sequential>
    </parallel>
</target>

<target name="fail" if="timeout">
    <fail message="Tomcat is not started in time"/>
</target>
```

Comment: This will not work since Tomcat starts to listen on :8080 immediately after server start. I did notice that the shutdown port (8005) did not start before the application was up, so I might be able to use this. Not sure if it's a proper methods though.

Comment: You can use GET task instead (http://goo.gl/vvo6N). You can pick one page of your application, and you can even check its content. GET also has a timeout, so you can use it as a replacement or additional check to waitfor. The Ant-Contrib (http://goo.gl/pty4L) task collection contains IF task, which is really useful to have conditional parts in ANT.